# the area of the Region common to the circle $r = 2$ and the cardioid $r=2(1-\cos(\theta))$

Tags: calculus

Trying to work this problem out, I got the integral $$\int_0^{\pi/2}(2+4\cos(\theta) - 2\cos^2(\theta))d\theta$$ Is this correct way to do this problem. And also, how would you get the second integral? Thanks for any help.

[image: Here is my question that i need some help one]

Comment: thank you @Mario G for fixing this!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: When you calculated "$\frac{1}{2}r^2$" there was I think a sign error. Also, if we are integrating from $0$ to $\pi/2$ we will have to double the integrand, since we are leaving out the part from $3\pi/2$ to $2\pi$. The second integral is just twice the area of a quarter-circle.

Comment: ok so i tried to redo the question, and so far I have gotten this. $$\int_0^{\pi/2}((1/2)(2(1-\cos(\theta)^2 - 2^2)d\theta$$

Comment: $$\int_0^{\pi/2}2((1+\cos^2(\theta) - 2\cos(\theta)-1)d\theta$$

Comment: am i doing this right so far?

Comment: In the first quadrant, also the fourth, the cardioid is inside the circle. The area from $0$ to $\pi/2$ is $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{2}4(1-\cos\theta)^2\,d\theta$. But we need to multiply by $2$ to deal with the fourth quadrant part. So we get $\int_0^{\pi/2}4(1-2\cos\theta+\cos^2\theta)\,d\theta$.  If your message above was intended for me to look at, it should have been addressed, I did not get notification.

Comment: so would the answer be A integral from 0 to pi/2 (1/2)(2-2cos(theta) + integral pi to 2pi (2^2)?